# Override Gradle settings in subprojects:

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have the following project structure

```
root/
    build.gradle
    projectA/
            build.gradle
    projectB/
            build.gradle
```

The `build.gradle` in `root` directory has an `allprojects{}` block.
The `build.gradle` files in `projectA` and `projectB` have `apply from` settings. I want to override these settings. Is there a way to do this from `root/build.gradle`?

Example `root/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
     ....
}
allprojects {
     .....
}
```

Example `root/projectA/build.gradle`:

```
apply from: http://hostname/xyz.gradle
dependencies {
     .....
}
```

Example `xyz.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
}
```

I want to override the FindBugs config, which is present in `xyz.gradle`.
I tried putting the config in a `subprojects` block in `root/build.gradle`, but that didn't work out.

Comment: Can you please clarify with example code for the `build.gradle` in all 3 folders? If the real code is too large or not open-source, please distill the problem down to a small example.

Comment: @MichaelEaster, I have edited the question to include sample code.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, you need to change `findbugs` settings in `build.gradle`. It's doable, have you tried it?

Comment: @Opal, I tried it. I put the setting in root/build.gradle, but that didn't work out.